# Python dictionary vs django.Template.Context

Tags: django, django-templates

Can i use any python dictionary as a context or should i use the one provided by django.template.Context?

What difference does it make?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to insert your (python-)dictionary into django request context, to have your variables for use in your template, like:

```
def some_view(request):
    my_data_dictionary={...}
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                              my_data_dictionary,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: so does my_data_dictionary gets placed inside django.template.Context when rendering the template?  like this Context(my_data_dictionary)?

Comment: this should be the case.